# Custom view doesn't draw Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I´m trying to display a moving cloud over a blue sky. The blue background is displayed but the cloud doesn't appear. I've tried the different approaches in other questions here but nothing works. My code is:

```
public class CloudBackground extends View {

Bitmap cloud;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
Paint paint = new Paint();
Rect rectangle = new Rect(0,0,100,100);

public CloudBackground(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    cloud = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.cloud1);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Rect back = new Rect();
    back.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

    Paint pBlue = new Paint();
    pBlue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    pBlue.setColor(Color.CYAN);

    canvas.drawRect(back, pBlue);

    drawCloud(x,y,canvas);

    if (x < canvas.getWidth())
        x = x + 10;
    else { 
        y = y + 10;
        x = 0;
    }
    invalidate();

}

private void drawCloud(int x2, int y2, Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(cloud, x2, y2,paint);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was finally solved using a.jpg instead a .png. As simple as that and with no reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Try this:

```
public CloudBackground(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context,attrs);
    cloud = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getApplicationContext().getResources(),R.drawable.cloud1);
}
```

Comment: I was missing brackets in the second part (already added in the description). However, I've included the first part, and commented the part when I move the clouds and still doesn't work :(

Comment: I edited my original post. try it and tell me what happens